# Optional argument of specific type

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

When using `argparse` how would one do if an option can take an optional parameter, but that has to be of a specific type. For example let's say I write a tool called `frob` that when the `-n` option is given truncates a file, but when provided a numerical value it would truncate to that length.

If using `add_argument('-n', nargs='?', const=0)` it would consume whatever the next argument is and if I use `add_argument('-n', nargs='?', type=int, const=0)` it would try that anyway and fail if it's not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make this sort of distinction in `argparse`.  `sys.argv` strings are allocated to an Action strictly on the basis of `nargs` and position.  If you specify

```
parser.add_argument('-n', nargs='?', type=int, const=0)
```

then `-n 1 --other` will work, `-n one --other` will fail because `int('one')` produces an Error.  The same applies to the `choices` test.  The Action has to use the strings that it is given, or fail.  Tests, if any, are applied after the strings are allocated, not before.

`optparse` has a different parsing routine.  It passes the whole commandline list to the option, lets it consume what it wants and return the rest.